# Change default file/image if not found for public access in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I migrated my website storage to google cloud storage, but the migration/upload was failed for some files because some reasons. By default, if the path/object doesnt exist in the GCS bucket will return XML like below:

```
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Details>No such object: bucket/the_file.png</Details>
</Error>
```

Can I change/customize that return to another file/image?

Comment: Ok, you got an error but do you have the source code to see what happens? Can you also describe your issue? Not sure to catch what help are your looking for

Comment: Sorry to make confused, I just want to change the error page(XML) to an image.

Answer (score 1):

If your static website is online by using a Cloud Storage bucket as is described in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website), you need to upload a public file in your bucket called 404.html, this file must have the html code that you desire to shown when an object doesn't exists.

After uploading the file `404.html` it is mandatory to run this [command](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/web) in the [cloud shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/launching-cloud-shell#launching_from_the_console) in order to define the error file

```
gsutil web set -e 404.html gs://www.example.com
```

In this [page](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/static-website#error-page) you can find more information about the `404.html` file